# Why Dhcp renewed ip address for some machines and not for the others

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, dhcp, ip-address, pfsense

so this is the situation i'm trying to understand:

The environnent is the following:

- a running **personal laptop** with dhcp on;
- a set of **4 VMS** running in the same network @ range
- **pfsense** to manage dhcp among other things, with a pool of addresses for dhcp, from .120 to .254

2 days ago, i added a new VM (Windows11) to the same network, and it started exhausting the dhcp pool address (*a windows problem, but that's another story*), and **Here's the problem:**

The ip addresses of the VMS were given one by one to the win11-vm via dhcp lease (*win11-vm try one then rejects it and moves on*), even though the VMS were running.. **How is this possible ?**

N.B: My laptop didn't have his ip@ changed (x.x.x.176), but i guess pfsense didn't arrive to this @ maybe..

Comment: Do you use "@" to mean "address"?

Comment: Default Network selection for VMs is NAT. VM App NAT provides DCHP. Is this conflicting with pfsense?

Comment: @gronostaj yes exactly.

Comment: @John i'm gonna check this now